# How to prevent plt.show() from making gui unreponsive

Tags: python, matplotlib, wxpython

I'm working on an app that plots a datafile when you drag and drop it onto a gui. The problem I have is that using plt.show() causes the gui to be disabled until I close the plot.

To avoid this I tried using `plt.ion()` (ie. interactive mode) and also `plt.show(block=False)`.

However both these methods only partially solve the problem because it causes some unwanted side effects such as resizing the plot doesn't actually resize it, you just end up with whatever was on your screen on the extended window space. Also clicking on the x (exit) button on the plot doesn't close it.

here is a minimal amount of code to showcase this:

```
import wx
import re
import tempfile
import numpy as np
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt

class PlottingManager():

    def plotData(self,filename, xcol, ycol):
        [tx,ty] = self.getData(filename,xcol,ycol)
        plt.plot(tx, ty)

    def getData(self,filename, xcol, ycol):
        print "Plotting : ", str(filename)
        fileIn = open(filename,'r')
        fileStr = fileIn.read()
        csvType = False
        if ',' in fileStr:
            csvType = True
        if csvType:

            data = np.genfromtxt(filename, unpack=True, delimiter=',')
        else:
            fileStr = re.sub('\s+', ' ', fileStr).strip()
            fp = tempfile.NamedTemporaryFile()
            fp.write(fileStr)
            data = np.genfromtxt(filename, unpack=True)

        tx = data[xcol]
        ty = data[ycol]
        return [tx,ty]

    def showPlot(self): #Function that calls plt.show()
        plt.grid(True);
        plt.legend();
        plt.ion()
        plt.show()

MENU_FILE_EXIT = wx.NewId()
DRAG_SOURCE    = wx.NewId()

class PlotFileDropTarget(wx.TextDropTarget):
    def __init__(self, PlottingManager, obj):
        wx.TextDropTarget.__init__(self)
        self.obj = obj
        self.plotManager = PlottingManager

    def OnDropText(self, x, y, data):
        self.obj.WriteText("Will plot | "+ data[7:-2] + '\n\n')
        self.plotManager.plotData(data[7:-2],0,1)
        self.plotManager.showPlot()

class MainWindow(wx.Frame):
    def __init__(self,parent,id,title):
        wx.Frame.__init__(self,parent, wx.ID_ANY, title, size = (750,600), style=wx.DEFAULT_FRAME_STYLE|wx.NO_FULL_REPAINT_ON_RESIZE)
        self.SetBackgroundColour(wx.WHITE)
        # Setup plotting manager
        self.plotManager = PlottingManager()
        # setup dragdrop box
        self.text = wx.TextCtrl(self, DRAG_SOURCE, "", pos=(0,0), size=(750,200), style = wx.TE_MULTILINE|wx.HSCROLL)
        self.dt1 = PlotFileDropTarget(self.plotManager,self.text)
        self.text.SetDropTarget(self.dt1)

        wx.EVT_RIGHT_DOWN(self.text, self.OnDragInit)
        self.Show()

    def CloseWindow(self, event):
        self.Close()

    def OnDragInit(self, event):
        tdo = wx.PyTextDataObject(self.text.GetStringSelection())
        tds = wx.DropSource(self.text)
        tds.SetData(tdo)
        tds.DoDragDrop(True)

class DropPlot(wx.App):
    def OnInit(self):
        frame = MainWindow(None, -1, "Drag data to plot")
        self.SetTopWindow(frame)
        return True

# main loop
app = DropPlot(0)
app.MainLoop()
```

Here's the datafile:

```
-0.0000000000 0.0000000000
-0.0108492172 0.1583380438
-0.0216984343 0.3166760876
-0.0325476515 0.4750141313
-0.0433968686 0.6333521751
-0.0542460858 0.7916902189
-0.0650953029 0.9500282627
-0.0759445201 1.1083663065
-0.0867937372 1.2667043503
-0.0976429544 1.4250423940
-0.1084921715 1.5833804378
-0.1193413887 1.7417184816
-0.1301906058 1.9000565254
-0.1410398230 2.0583945692
-0.1518890401 2.2167326130
-0.1627382573 2.3750706567
-0.1735874745 2.5334087005
-0.1844366916 2.6917467443
-0.1952859088 2.8500847881
-0.2061351259 3.0084228319
-0.2169843431 3.1667608756
-0.2278335602 3.3250989194
-0.2386827774 3.4834369632
-0.2495319945 3.6417750070
-0.2603812117 3.8001130508
-0.2712304288 3.9584510946
-0.2820796460 4.1167891383
-0.2929288631 4.2751271821
-0.3037780803 4.4334652259
-0.3146272974 4.5918032697
-0.3254765146 4.7501413135
-0.3363257317 4.9084793573
-0.3471749489 5.0668174010
-0.3580241661 5.2251554448
-0.3688733832 5.3834934886
-0.3797226004 5.5418315324
-0.3905718175 5.7001695762
-0.4014210347 5.8585076199
-0.4122702518 6.0168456637
-0.4231194690 6.1751837075
-0.4339686861 6.3335217513
-0.4448179033 6.4918597951
-0.4556671204 6.6501978389
-0.4665163376 6.8085358826
-0.4773655547 6.9668739264
-0.4882147719 7.1252119702
-0.4990639890 7.2835500140
-0.5099132062 7.4418880578
-0.5207624234 7.6002261016
-0.5316116405 7.7585641453
-0.5424608577 7.9169021891
-0.5533100748 8.0752402329
-0.5641592920 8.2335782767
-0.5750085091 8.3919163205
-0.5858577263 8.5502543642
-0.5967069434 8.7085924080
-0.6075561606 8.8669304518
-0.6184053777 9.0252684956
-0.6292545949 9.1836065394
-0.6401038120 9.3419445832
-0.6509530292 9.5002826269
-0.6618022463 9.6586206707
-0.6726514635 9.8169587145
-0.6835006806 9.9752967583
-0.6943498978 10.1336348021
-0.7051991150 10.2919728459
-0.7160483321 10.4503108896
-0.7268975493 10.6086489334
-0.7377467664 10.7669869772
-0.7485959836 10.9253250210
-0.7594452007 11.0836630648
-0.7702944179 11.2420011085
-0.7811436350 11.4003391523
-0.7919928522 11.5586771961
-0.8028420693 11.7170152399
-0.8136912865 11.8753532837
-0.8245405036 12.0336913275
-0.8353897208 12.1920293712
-0.8462389379 12.3503674150
-0.8570881551 12.5087054588
-0.8679373723 12.6670435026
-0.8787865894 12.8253815464
-0.8896358066 12.9837195901
-0.9004850237 13.1420576339
-0.9113342409 13.3003956777
-0.9221834580 13.4587337215
-0.9330326752 13.6170717653
-0.9438818923 13.7754098091
-0.9547311095 13.9337478528
-0.9655803266 14.0920858966
-0.9764295438 14.2504239404
-0.9872787609 14.4087619842
-0.9981279781 14.5671000280
-1.0089771952 14.7254380718
-1.0198264124 14.8837761155
-1.0306756296 15.0421141593
-1.0415248467 15.2004522031
-1.0523740639 15.3587902469
-1.0632232810 15.5171282907
-1.0740724982 15.6754663344
-1.0849217153 15.8338043782
-1.0957709325 15.9921424220
-1.1234471716 16.1497056125
-1.1511234108 16.3072688030
-1.1787996500 16.4648319936
-1.2064758892 16.6223951841
-1.2341521284 16.7799583746
-1.2618283675 16.9375215651
-1.2895046067 17.0950847556
-1.3171808459 17.2526479461
-1.3448570851 17.4102111367
-1.3725333243 17.5677743272
-1.4002095634 17.7253375177
-1.4278858026 17.8829007082
-1.4555620418 18.0404638987
-1.4832382810 18.1980270892
-1.5109145201 18.3555902798
-1.5385907593 18.5131534703
-1.5662669985 18.6707166608
-1.5939432377 18.8282798513
-1.6216194769 18.9858430418
-1.6492957160 19.1434062323
-1.6769719552 19.3009694229
-1.7046481944 19.4585326134
-1.7323244336 19.6160958039
-1.7600006728 19.7736589944
-1.7876769119 19.9312221849
-1.8153531511 20.0887853754
-1.8430293903 20.2463485660
-1.8707056295 20.4039117565
-1.8983818686 20.5614749470
-1.9260581078 20.7190381375
-1.9537343470 20.8766013280
-1.9814105862 21.0341645185
-2.0090868254 21.1917277090
-2.0367630645 21.3492908996
-2.0644393037 21.5068540901
-2.0921155429 21.6644172806
-2.1197917821 21.8219804711
-2.1474680213 21.9795436616
-2.1751442604 22.1371068521
-2.2028204996 22.2946700427
-2.2304967388 22.4522332332
-2.2581729780 22.6097964237
-2.2858492171 22.7673596142
-2.3135254563 22.9249228047
-2.3412016955 23.0824859952
-2.3688779347 23.2400491858
-2.3965541739 23.3976123763
-2.4242304130 23.5551755668
-2.4519066522 23.7127387573
-2.4795828914 23.8703019478
-2.5072591306 24.0278651383
-2.5349353698 24.1854283289
-2.5626125527 24.3429915194
-2.6327781321 24.4799792649
-2.7029437115 24.6169670104
-2.7731092909 24.7539547558
-2.8432748702 24.8909425013
-2.9134404496 25.0279302468
-2.9836060290 25.1649179923
-3.0537716084 25.3019057378
-3.1239371877 25.4388934833
-3.1941027671 25.5758812288
-3.2642683465 25.7128689743
-3.3344339259 25.8498567198
-3.4045995052 25.9868444653
-3.4747650846 26.1238322108
-3.5449306640 26.2608199563
-3.6150962434 26.3978077017
-3.6852618227 26.5347954472
-3.7554274021 26.6717831927
-3.8255929815 26.8087709382
-3.8957585609 26.9457586837
-3.9659241402 27.0827464292
-4.0360897196 27.2197341747
-4.1062552990 27.3567219202
-4.1764208784 27.4937096657
-4.2465864577 27.6306974112
-4.3167542750 27.7676851567
-4.3120630353 27.6085617007
-4.3073717956 27.4494382448
-4.3026805559 27.2903147889
-4.2979893162 27.1311913330
-4.2932980765 26.9720678771
-4.2886068368 26.8129444212
-4.2839155971 26.6538209653
-4.2792243573 26.4946975094
-4.2745331176 26.3355740534
-4.2698418779 26.1764505975
-4.2651506382 26.0173271416
-4.2604593985 25.8582036857
-4.2557681588 25.6990802298
-4.2510769191 25.5399567739
-4.2463856794 25.3808333180
-4.2416944397 25.2217098620
-4.2370032000 25.0625864061
-4.2323119603 24.9034629502
-4.2276207206 24.7443394943
-4.2229294808 24.5852160384
-4.2182382411 24.4260925825
-4.2135470014 24.2669691266
-4.2088557617 24.1078456706
-4.2041645220 23.9487222147
-4.1994732823 23.7895987588
-4.1947820426 23.6304753029
-4.1900908029 23.4713518470
-4.1853995632 23.3122283911
-4.1807083235 23.1531049352
-4.1760170838 22.9939814793
-4.1713258441 22.8348580233
-4.1666346043 22.6757345674
-4.1619433646 22.5166111115
-4.1572521249 22.3574876556
-4.1525608852 22.1983641997
-4.1478696455 22.0392407438
-4.1431784058 21.8801172879
-4.1384871661 21.7209938319
-4.1337959264 21.5618703760
-4.1291046867 21.4027469201
-4.1244134470 21.2436234642
-4.1197222073 21.0845000083
-4.1150309676 20.9253765524
-4.1103397278 20.7662530965
-4.1056484881 20.6071296406
-4.1009572484 20.4480061846
-4.0962660087 20.2888827287
-4.0915747690 20.1297592728
-4.0868835293 19.9706358169
-4.0821922896 19.8115123610
-4.0775010499 19.6523889051
-4.0728098102 19.4932654492
-4.0681185705 19.3341419932
-4.0634273308 19.1750185373
-4.0587360911 19.0158950814
-4.0540448513 18.8567716255
-4.0493536116 18.6976481696
-4.0446623719 18.5385247137
-4.0399711322 18.3794012578
-4.0352798925 18.2202778018
-4.0305886528 18.0611543459
-4.0258974131 17.9020308900
-4.0212061734 17.7429074341
-4.0165149337 17.5837839782
-4.0118236940 17.4246605223
-4.0071324543 17.2655370664
-4.0024412146 17.1064136105
-3.9977499748 16.9472901545
-3.9930587351 16.7881666986
-3.9883674954 16.6290432427
-3.9836762557 16.4699197868
-3.9789850160 16.3107963309
-3.9742937763 16.1516728750
-3.9696025366 15.9925494191
-3.9649112969 15.8334259631
-3.9602200572 15.6743025072
-3.9555288175 15.5151790513
-3.9508375778 15.3560555954
-3.9461463381 15.1969321395
-3.9414550983 15.0378086836
-3.9367638586 14.8786852277
-3.9320726189 14.7195617718
-3.9273813792 14.5604383158
-3.9226901395 14.4013148599
-3.9179988998 14.2421914040
-3.9133076601 14.0830679481
-3.9086164204 13.9239444922
-3.9039251807 13.7648210363
-3.8992339410 13.6056975804
-3.8945427013 13.4465741244
-3.8898514616 13.2874506685
-3.8851602218 13.1283272126
-3.8804689821 12.9692037567
-3.8757777424 12.8100803008
-3.8710865027 12.6509568449
-3.8663952630 12.4918333890
-3.8617040233 12.3327099330
-3.8570127836 12.1735864771
-3.8523215439 12.0144630212
-3.8476303042 11.8553395653
-3.8429390645 11.6962161094
-3.8382478248 11.5370926535
-3.8335565851 11.3779691976
-3.8288653453 11.2188457417
-3.8241741056 11.0597222857
-3.8194828659 10.9005988298
-3.8147916262 10.7414753739
-3.8101003865 10.5823519180
-3.8054091468 10.4232284621
-3.8007179071 10.2641050062
-3.7960266674 10.1049815503
-3.7913354277 9.9458580943
-3.7866441880 9.7867346384
-3.7819529483 9.6276111825
-3.7772617086 9.4684877266
-3.7725704688 9.3093642707
-3.7678792291 9.1502408148
-3.7631879894 8.9911173589
-3.7584967497 8.8319939029
-3.7538055100 8.6728704470
-3.7491142703 8.5137469911
-3.7444230306 8.3546235352
-3.7397317909 8.1955000793
-3.7350405512 8.0363766234
-3.7303493115 7.8772531675
-3.7256580718 7.7181297116
-3.7209668321 7.5590062556
-3.7162755923 7.3998827997
-3.7115843526 7.2407593438
-3.7068931129 7.0816358879
-3.7022018732 6.9225124320
-3.6975106335 6.7633889761
-3.6928193938 6.6042655202
-3.6881281541 6.4451420642
-3.6834369144 6.2860186083
-3.6787456747 6.1268951524
-3.6740544350 5.9677716965
-3.6693631953 5.8086482406
-3.6646719556 5.6495247847
-3.6599807158 5.4904013288
-3.6552894761 5.3312778729
-3.6505982364 5.1721544169
-3.6459069967 5.0130309610
-3.6412157570 4.8539075051
-3.6365245173 4.6947840492
-3.6318332776 4.5356605933
-3.6271420379 4.3765371374
-3.6224507982 4.2174136815
-3.6177595585 4.0582902255
-3.6130683188 3.8991667696
-3.6083770791 3.7400433137
-3.6036858393 3.5809198578
-3.5989945996 3.4217964019
-3.5943033599 3.2626729460
-3.5896178116 3.1035494901
```

Comment: As was commented as answer below, don't use `ion()`. However the way you have it here, doesn't use that anyway, so it should in principle work and there seems to be a problem with the code involved. I've never worked with wx in my life, but just looking at the code I feel that `self.plotManager = PlottingManager` should really be `self.plotManager = PlottingManager()`, so you would need an instance of that class, not the class itself, right?

Comment: No, what you are saying would create a new object of the class. What I've done is pass on an exisiting object.

Comment: Oh, sorry, that is really confusing. Best don't ever shadow class names locally.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

What you're trying to do doesn't make much sense.

Interactive mode responds to mouse events, etc., by taking over the main thread to run its own event loop. That works fine with [`show()`](https://matplotlib.org/api/_as_gen/matplotlib.pyplot.show.html), which blocks and runs its event loop until you close the window. But of course if your app has a GUI that's expecting to run its own event loop, it won't run.

`show(block=False)` is documented as "experimental". And it's hard to see how it could integrate nicely with every GUI framework on every platform without a whole lot of hackiness. So it's not surprising that it has some glitches. And there's probably nothing anyone can do for you. (Well, if you can write a detailed-enough bug report and file it with `matplotlib`, maybe someone will figure out a way to improve it and you'll get a fix in a few months…)

However, there is a pretty easy workaround: Run `matplotlib` in its own separate process.

Exactly how you design things and where you put the process boundary is up to you to experiment with and code up, but my first thought is that all of `PlotManager` could become a simple proxy to code in the background. That way, the only things you have to pickle and send over a queue are filenames and a couple of numbers, instead of numpy arrays and plot objects and the like. (Plus, it means `OnDropText` can return almost immediately, instead of blocking your GUI for however long it takes to read, process, and plot the array.)

The one problem you're likely to have is that in Python 2.x, `multiprocessing` on Unix (including macOS) works by forking the process, and that can play havoc with GUIs without some painful workarounds. If you have PyQt5 or PySide2 installed, apparently telling matplotlib to use one of them takes care of those workarounds magically, but I haven't verified that. If that doesn't work, the other option is to get the backport of `multiprocessing` from 3.4 to 2.x, or (I think) the forked version `multiprocess`. Then you can use the `forkserver` or `spawn` start method, and the problem goes away.

There are some examples on the matplotlib website, like [this one](https://matplotlib.org/gallery/misc/multiprocess_sgskip.html), and elsewhere.